# Can you use DSL in a Drools decision table?

Tags: drools

Can I use Domain Specific Language (DSL) in a Drools decision table (.xls file)?

I created a .dsl file for my decision table but I'm getting Drools syntax errors whenever I try to use an "alias" in the decision table.

```
    # Simple DSL example file

[keyword]avoid looping=no-loop true
[when]There is a Customer=$c:Customer()
[when]- with age between {low:\d*} and {high:\d*}=age >= {low}, age <= {high}
[when]- who is older than {low:\d*}=age > {low}
[when]- without a Category set=category == Customer.Category.NA
[then]Set Customer Category to {category:\w*}=modify($c)\{setCategory(Customer.Category.{category})\};
```

For example if I use the alias "There is a Customer" in my decision table, I get:

```
Line 8:8 mismatched input 'is' in rule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The decision table parser makes firm assumptions about what to expect in the header where a pattern with parentheses is a sort of "landmark" into which values from the column below are to be inserted.

There is no standard procedure for passing the result of the decision table compilation to the DSL expander, although you might work around that by catching the output of the former and use it as a DSLR file.

I don't see the benefit of combining DSL with a decision table. Although the intent with both is to make rule authoring for non-programmers easier, decision tables emphasize the idea that simple rules (written by programmers) can be repeated by varying literal date, whereas the DSL approach is provided as a syntactic sugar for writing a multitude of varying rules without the necessity of mastering the DRL syntax.